# Table with huge width leaves surrounding div

Tags: css

I have a problem with the following code:

```
<div style="background: #CCCCCC;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <!-- many td's with a width of, say 40px -->
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is: since the large number of td's exceeds 100% of the browser's width, the surrounding div should grow to more than 100%, but it doesn't. In fact, the gray background stops at 100% and it looks as if the table leaves the surrounding div. I tried to use all possible "display" variants for the table, but nothing helped.

Thanks

Comment: i think that would cut big chunks of his table..

Comment: Can you post a complete code example and if possible a jsFiddle, because a bare bones example doesn't support your issue (http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gaWCE/).

Comment: Overflow will cut off his table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can do is used `table-layout: fixed;` which should be associated with `word-wrap: break-word;` so that your table doesn't get weird with long unbreaked `td` strings or use `overflow: auto;` for the container `div`

```
table {
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: /* Whatever you want */;
}

table td {
   width: /* Whatever you want */;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Or use

```
div {
   width: /* Some fixed width here */;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: @Michael You should've told me before, background colors break when they exceed viewport widths so either give fixed width to your div, else use `min-width` or give background color to the table http://jsfiddle.net/PFJG8/2/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Yeah, a solution with a fixed with would of course work, but are there any dynamic solutions?

Comment: I have to agree with @Mr.Alien , is it possible to put background on your table OP?

Comment: @user1742364 Generally `min-width` is used but better to go with the table background instead, if you want you can also use `border-collapse` and border 0 to hide borders too

Comment: Okay, but what about this example, the grey background should again go over the whole width http://jsfiddle.net/x7aSW/ This would require that the surrounding div grows with the table's width.

Comment: @user1742364 I said you'll need to give `min-width` or `width` for divs :) http://jsfiddle.net/x7aSW/1/ this is often bugging for designers, when their background images stop rendering after viewport, and `table-layout` property is for the table and not for divs

Comment: So there is no dynamic solution, right? Your suggested solution gets into trouble, too, at some point http://jsfiddle.net/x7aSW/2/

Comment: @user1742364 Way to go for JS or jQuery :)

Comment: That's what I tried to avoid...Anyway, thank you for your help.